# Removing Subqueries to improve query performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

my sql query performance is slowing my application and want to get rid of this. i have two sql tables with different schema and I want to get a combined output as i have written in query but the query is taking almost 20 seconds to run with tbl_complaint has 400k+ rows and tbl_sales has 100k+ rows. when i searched some optimization feature found few solutions like indexing which i have done and couldn't succeed. another recommendation was to **remove subqueries which is primary cause for running time** but i tried doing it but couldn't. here's the query which i am running

```
SELECT Sum(Isnull(B.cqty, 0)), 
       Sum(A.qty) 
FROM   (SELECT month_date, 
               Sum(salesquantity) AS Qty 
        FROM   tbl_sales 
        WHERE  month_date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 120) 
               AND month_date >= Dateadd(month, -12, 
                                 CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 120)) 
        GROUP  BY month_date) AS A 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT month_date, 
                         Count(*) AS CQty 
                  FROM   tbl_complaints 
                  WHERE  warranty = 'Within Warranty' 
                         AND complainttype = 'Product Complaint' 
                         AND month_date <= CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                           '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 120 
                                           ) 
                         AND month_date >= Dateadd(month, -12, 
                                           CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                           '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 120 
                                           )) 
                  GROUP  BY month_date) AS B 
              ON A.month_date = B.month_date
```

and schema of the tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_complaints] 
  ( 
     [branch]                [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [srno]                  [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [dateopened]            [DATETIME] NULL, 
     [dateclosed]            [DATETIME] NULL, 
     [nameofthecustomer]     [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [city]                  [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [district]              [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [state]                 [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [mob]                   [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [product]               [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [prdcategory]           [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [prdsubcategory]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [model]                 [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [serialno]              [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [batchno]               [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [billable]              [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [mfgunitcode]           [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [warrantystatus]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [custreportedcomplaint] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [recievercomments]      [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [actualcomplaint]       [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [complaintcategory]     [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [complaintsubcategory]  [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [actiontaken]           [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [acualcomplaintinpcb]   [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [brandnameofspares]     [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [srstatus]              [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [srchannel]             [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [srtouchpoint]          [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [dealerpointname]       [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [ascname]               [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [attendedtechnician]    [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [substatus]             [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [resolutiontime]        [FLOAT] NULL, 
     [reasonfordelay]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [batchcomplaint]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [productrelated]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [srresolution]          [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [sitedistancekm]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [technicianobservation] [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [purchasedate]          [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [rndcomplaint]          [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [month_text]            [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [qtr]                   [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [month_date]            [DATETIME] NULL, 
     [fiscal year]           [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [warranty]              [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [branch2]               [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [zone]                  [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [dept]                  [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [complainttype]         [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [model1]                [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [model2]                [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [category1]             [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [category2]             [NVARCHAR](255) NULL 
  ) 
ON [PRIMARY] 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_sales] 
  ( 
     [branch]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [model]         [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [month_text]    [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [qtr]           [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [month_date]    [DATETIME] NULL, 
     [fiscal  year]          [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [salesquantity] [FLOAT] NULL, 
     [salesvalue]    [FLOAT] NULL, 
     [branch2]       [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [zone]          [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [model1]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [model2]        [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [category1]     [NVARCHAR](255) NULL, 
     [category2]     [NVARCHAR](255) NULL 
  ) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

kindly help me in **removing the subqueries by replacing with joins**

Comment: First of all, start over. [`VARCHAR`and `NVARCHAR` need a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). They will have a length if the tables already exist, but if these are your creation scripts you have a problem.

Comment: That code is hard to read, format it

Comment: joining 2 subquerues containing 12 rows each is not going to be slow but why do you join by month and then sum over the resultset? Also I don't see any indexes in your tables.

Comment: i have tried adding indexes but it was giving me error like wait operation timed out but still i was able to add indexes to month_date,model

Comment: You should add the indexes you do have to the question

Comment: You should fix your table design, for example, `complainttype` should be an integer, and you should have a separate table that links that integer to the value 'Product Complaint'. I'm guessing nearly all columns have this issue, making the table way bigger than it would need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please give below code one try.

Changes done:

1. Calculated Required date once and used, instead of converting for every comparison
2. Converted subqueries into temp tables

   ```
    Declare @StartDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 120) 

    Declare @EndDate DATETIME = Dateadd(month, -12, 
                                     CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-11-01 00:00:00', 120)) 

    SELECT month_date, 
           Sum(salesquantity) AS Qty 
    INTO #MS
    FROM   tbl_sales 
    WHERE  month_date <= @StartDate
            AND month_date >= @EndDate 
    GROUP  BY month_date


    SELECT month_date, 
           Count(*) AS CQty 
    INTO #MQ
    FROM   tbl_complaints 
    WHERE  warranty = 'Within Warranty' 
            AND complainttype = 'Product Complaint' 
            AND month_date <= @StartDate
            AND month_date >= @EndDate
    GROUP  BY month_date

    SELECT Sum(Isnull(B.cqty, 0)), 
           Sum(A.qty) 
    FROM  #MS  AS A 
    LEFT JOIN #MQ AS B  ON A.month_date = B.month_date
   ```